# Installshield Packagefortheweb3 to Wix converter?

Tags: wix, installshield

Does anybody now of an automatic way or converter for bringing old Installshield PackageForTheWeb 3 PFW-files into Wix Bundle XML-format?

PFW-files are just flat INI-files so I hope somebody already brought them to the WiX toolset or has some guidance.

I use Wix 3.7

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any such library, however if you could build the .msi you can use the WiX tool [Dark](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/dark.htm) to decompile it into WiX source.